# js-анимация через raf

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Реализовал анимацию через RequestAnimationFrame. Во всех браузерах всё плавненько, только в FF для android рывки. Дебажил свою анимацию в timeline и добился неплохих результатов, исключил лишние repaint, но такое ощущение, что ff всё равно всё перерисовывает.
кАК МОЖНО РЕШИТЬ ТАКОЙ КАСЯК? :)

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не использовать css-анимацию вместо js?

Comment: Использовал transition для отрисовки height  и мне кажется производительность ещё похуже. [club.orgfree.com](http://club.orgfree.com) анимация верхнего меню на небольших экранах.